# Curl can not download file with php

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to download a file using PHP and CURL, here is my code:

```php
set_time_limit(0);
// Set file to write to
$file = fopen($nameGenerated['path'], 'w+');
$ch = curl_init();
if ($ch == false) {
    die('Failed to create curl handle');
}
// Set Curl options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, str_replace(" ", "%20", $uri));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
// get curl response
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($file);
```

The file is empty and `curl_exec` always returns false. When I tried to get the errors using `curl_error($ch)` there was no error.

Note: I am using Yii2.

Can someone help me understand what's the matter?

Comment: Where is `$uri` set, what does it contain?

Comment: It is sent with the request, at the moment it is http:://localhost/practice.html

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by using the ipv4 addess instead of the usual 127.0.0.1. Now I know the problem, the CURL was excepting an ip address, not the localhost or 127.0.0.1. 
Thanks for all the people who tried to help!